# Android (Programmatic) layout not showing 2nd textView when wrapping 1rst textView

Tags: android, android-layout

Structure of a "list" made programatically:

```
ScrollView
->LinearLayout (itemRow)
-->LinearLayout (itemTitle)
--->TextView (title)
--->TextView (price)
--> (other layouts)...
... and start again with itemRow
```

When the title TextView text is correctly wrapped, price ***(gratis)*** is not shown.

[image]

Code:

```
    LayoutParams p=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); 

    TextView title=new TextView(ctx);
    title.setText(e.getTitle());
    title.setTextAppearance(ctx, R.style.eList_Title);
    TextView price=new TextView(ctx);
    price.setPadding(2, 1, 1, 1);
    price.setSingleLine(true);
    if (e.getPrice().doubleValue()==0) {
        price.setText('('+getString(R.string.e_free)+')');
        price.setTextColor(colorGreenFree);
    } else {
        price.setText('('+NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(e.getPrice())+')');
        price.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    LinearLayout llTitle=new LinearLayout(ctx);
    llTitle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_silver_red);
    llTitle.setLayoutParams(llpMatchParentWrapContent);
    llTitle.addView(title);
    llTitle.addView(price);
```

Note: if price.setSingleLine(true); is removed I get this result:

[image]

P.D.: 
I've tried with RelativeLayout, and have same problem.

Comment: Why don't you try with the Listview by implementing the Custom Layout for the ListView. Like this http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/07/custom-listview-for-android.html

Answer (score 1):

The TextView is too wide and is pushing the second off the the right.

An easier way to acheive this might be to use a single TextView and some HTML to colour 'gratis'.

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.format("%s <font color="#00FF00">(%s)</font>", name, gratis)));
```

Comment: Using this doesn't work:  strTitle=Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FF0000\">("+NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(event.getPrice())+")</font>");

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex for your answer, finally solved this way:

```
        Spannable titleSpan= null;
        String strPrice=null;
        if (e.getPrice().doubleValue()==0) {
            strPrice='('+getString(R.string.e_free)+')';
            titleSpan=new SpannableString(e.getTitle()+strPrice);
            titleSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), e.getTitle().length(), e.getTitle().length()+strPrice.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INTERMEDIATE);
        } else {
    strPrice='('+NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(e.getPrice())+')';
            titleSpan=new SpannableString(e.getTitle()+strPrice);
            titleSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), e.getTitle().length(), e.getTitle().length()+strPrice.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INTERMEDIATE);
        }
        title.setText(titleSpan);
```